# How to get classes incrementally compiled by SBT?

Tags: scala, sbt

The result of `compile` task in sbt is of type [`Analysis`](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.12/api/index.html#sbt.inc.Analysis).
I want to find all `java.lang.Class`es that are compiled in last compilation.
Is that possible at all?